# Gauge chart maximum value

Tags: charts, google-visualization, max, google-gauges

Here is the code for simple Google gauge chart copied from [Google code playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#gauge).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['gauge']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to change the maximum value for these gauges? When I given `var options = {          max: 500};` in options it set 500 for all three gauges. But Is it possible to give different maximums for different gauges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make 3 different gauge charts. You can use the same DataTable, but use only one row for each individual chart using a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView). Currently there is no way to set the values of the gauges individually within the API. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-visualization-api/w7iq2APIdiI) from 2011 in Google Groups that says the same thing.

(Chances are this isn't a very high priority. If you want to do it more simply, you can use [Control Wrappers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#controlwrapperobject) to link all of them without separate DataViews)

Comment: Ok @jmac. One more small doubt. Can I set variable as a maximum value. ie, some value from any cell of datatable.